# time issue in writing event in iPhone Calendar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to write event in iPhone's default calendar but i am facing issue in time difference ,I am getting start Date 18-02-2014 08:00 PM and End Date 25-02-2014 11:30 PM I am using code.But it is writing start Date  18-02-2014 12:00 PM and end Date 25-02-2014 12:30 PM.I don't know where I m wrong .How can i write it on same time.

```
-(void)writeEventwithTitle:(NSString*)aTitle startDate:(NSDate*)strtDate endDate:(NSDate*)ndDate{
    _eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    [_eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError* error){
        if (!granted) {
            return ;
        }
       EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:_eventStore];
        event.title = aTitle;
        event.startDate = strtDate;
        event.endDate = ndDate;
        [event setCalendar:[_eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        NSError* err;

        [_eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanFutureEvents commit:YES error:&err];
    }];
}
-(void)startWritingEvent{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < [_eventArray count]; i++) {
        id dict= [_eventArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString* eventTitle = [dict objectForKey:Title];
        NSDictionary* eventBeginArray = [dict objectForKey:EventBegin];

        NSDate* startDate = [self dateFromDate:[eventBeginArray objectForKey:StartDate] andTime:[eventBeginArray objectForKey:StartTime]];
         NSDate* endDate = [self dateFromDate:[eventBeginArray objectForKey:EndDate] andTime:[eventBeginArray objectForKey:EndTime]];

        [self writeEventwithTitle:eventTitle startDate:startDate endDate:endDate];

    }
}
-(NSDate*)dateFromDate:(NSString*)date andTime:(NSString*)time{
    NSString *eventDttm = [[NSString alloc] init];
    eventDttm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",date,time];
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm a"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    //conversion of NSString to NSDate
     NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:eventDttm];

    return dateFromString;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is your issue, but is something you also need to be aware of. If the user has turned off 24 hour format on their phone and only display times in 12 hour clock, asking for `HH` will not return a 24 hour clock hour - [have a look](http://www.flexicoder.com/blog/index.php/2013/10/ios-24-hour-date-format/)

Comment: Are you aware of timezones and that iOS gives dates in GMT if not asked otherwise, so for example in logging NSDate objects via NSLog?

Comment: @thanks for yr advice but i am getting this time from server.